# Edit able select box with grouping in the options

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Hello all I am working on drop down/Select box.

Here is my requirement.

I want to have a drop down box having groups of options in it as well as it should be edit able.

For grouping i have used `<optgroup>` and to make it editable i have used jquery.editable.select plugin. But the issue is that as soon as I call editable on my selectbox the grouping gets disappeared.

Here is my code.

```
<select class= "myclass">
   <optgroup label="Dairy products">
      <option>Cheese</option>
      <option>Egg</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Vegetables">
      <option>Cabbage</option>
      <option>Lettuce</option>
      <option>Beans</option>
      <option>Onions</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

When I do this the grouping disappears.

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){
      $(this).editableSelect({
          bg_iframe: true,
          case_sensitive: false,
          items_then_scroll: 10,
      });
});
```

Can any one please help me to find a way so that I can achieve both edit and grouping.

Also I have also find a plugin [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) But i am unable to edit the select box.
Also I don't want to add the option dynamically in my list. I just want to allow user to enter the text.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using something like the jQuery autocomplete plugin. This would give you a text box that you could simply enter the text in, but also provide a selectable set of text. This has similar semantics to a textbox + select, but I think the interface looks less cluttered.